# How can we maintain insertion order for set when using spring mvc and hibernate with annotation

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, collections, insertion-order

My requirement is to convert an image to thumbnail, the first image selected by user should get converted to thumbnail, but as of now since i am using set it is not happening. How can i implement this with spring mvc and hibernate. I tried using like the code mentioned below; but it threw error.

```
Set<UserDefinedClass> object = new LinkedHashSet<UserDefinedClass>
```

this is done in POJO.

Comment: thanks for the reply but this is not my issue. i want to know how to take the first image selected by user for converting into thumbnail. Thumbnail conversion code already i have and working fine.

Comment: updated your code in question. The question seems to be about choosing right data structure.

Comment: You should update the relevant code inside the question. What kind exception you get.?

Comment: For maintaing insertion order you have chosen the LinkedHashset .Now what do you exactly want from your frameworks?

Comment: i have put LinkedHashSet but it is not taking the first image still.

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: And how does the code look like where you try to retrieve the first image? You should post all relevant information, otherwise it's not possible to help you.